# change referenced array to regular array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, reference

I have this array(output of `var_dump()`):

```
array (size=32)
  2 => &
    array (size=3)
      'data' =>
        array (size=3)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'options' => string '2' (length=1)
      'attr' =>
        array (size=2)
          'rel' => string 'container' (length=9)
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'children' =>
        array (size=3)
          3 => &
            array (size=3)
              'data' =>
                array (size=3)
                  'parent_id' => string '2' (length=1)
                  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
                  'options' => string '3' (length=1)
              'attr' =>
                array (size=2)
                  'rel' => string 'container' (length=9)
                  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
              'children' =>
                array (size=2)
                  8 => &
                    array (size=3)
                      'data' =>
                        array (size=3)
                          'parent_id' => string '3' (length=1)
                          'id' => string '8' (length=1)
                          'options' => string '1' (length=1)
                      'attr' =>
                        array (size=2)
                          'rel' => string 'container' (length=9)
                          'id' => string '8' (length=1)
                      'children' =>
                        array (size=2)
                          11 => &
                            array (size=3)
                              'data' =>
                                array (size=3)
                                  'parent_id' => string '8' (length=1)
                                  'id' => string '11' (length=2)
                                  'options' => string '3' (length=1)
                              'attr' =>
                                array (size=2)
                                  'rel' => string 'container' (length=9)
                                  'id' => string '11' (length=2)
```

As you can see some of key are passed by reference, I want change this array to regular array, like this:

```
array (size=32)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'data' =>
        array (size=3)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'options' => string '2' (length=1)
      'attr' =>
        array (size=2)
          'rel' => string 'container' (length=9)
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'children' =>
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              'data' =>
                array (size=3)
                  'parent_id' => string '2' (length=1)
                  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
                  'options' => string '3' (length=1)
              'attr' =>
                array (size=2)
                  'rel' => string 'container' (length=9)
                  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
              'children' =>
                array (size=2)
                  0 => 
                    array (size=3)
                      'data' =>
                        array (size=3)
                          'parent_id' => string '3' (length=1)
                          'id' => string '8' (length=1)
                          'options' => string '1' (length=1)
                      'attr' =>
                        array (size=2)
                          'rel' => string 'container' (length=9)
                          'id' => string '8' (length=1)
                      'children' =>
                        array (size=2)
                          0 => 
                            array (size=3)
                              'data' =>
                                array (size=3)
                                  'parent_id' => string '8' (length=1)
                                  'id' => string '11' (length=2)
                                  'options' => string '3' (length=1)
                              'attr' =>
                                array (size=2)
                                  'rel' => string 'container' (length=9)
                                  'id' => string '11' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) and [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($array), true);
```

Also you could use this function.

```
function deReferencing($value)
    {
    if (is_array($value))
        {
        $return = array();
        foreach ($value as $key => $item)
            {
            unset($value[$key]);
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
               $return[] = deReferencing($item);
               } else {
               $return[$key] = deReferencing($item);
               }  
            }
        }
    else
        $return = $value;

    return $return;
    }

$array = deReferencing($array);
```

Comment: @ArashMousavi, what do you mean?

Comment: I tried your approach, but it didn't worked, and output array was as same as first array, and it hasn't changed...

Comment: @ArashMousavi, sorry. It's not working. I'll change my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine :)
but another issue is remain, how to make array keys squential from 0?

Comment: I tried updated function, but it change none numeric keys like 'id', 'parent_id',...